Snake diagram and caption with tikz-cd
I want to create the following picture.

The current code is as follows. However, I want to add 7 zeros and a caption. But adding them breaks my diagram. Regarding the caption, I may need to change from TikZ to other tools. Thank you for your help.
   \begin{document}
      \documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
        \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
        %\usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage{tikz-cd}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
        
        \usepackage{float}
        
        
        \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
        \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整
        
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        
        \usepackage{lipsum}   
        \tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
                   diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
                   }
        
        
        
        
        \DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
        \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
        \DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
        \DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}
        
        
        
         \[
            \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            \mathrm{Ker}F\arrow[r,hookrightarrow] \arrow[d, hookrightarrow] \& \Sha(E/K)[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d, hookrightarrow] \& {\mathrm{Ker}H} \arrow[d,hookrightarrow]
            \\
            {H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),E(L))}\arrow[r,"\mathrm{inf}"] \arrow[d, "F"] \&
            H^1(G_K,E)[2] \arrow[r, twoheadrightarrow, "\mathrm{res}"] \arrow[d,"G"] \&
            \mathrm{res}(H^1(G_K,E)[2]) \arrow[d,"H"]
            \\
            {\bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L_w/K_v),E(L_w))} \arrow[r,hookrightarrow] \arrow[d, twoheadrightarrow] \&
            \bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d,twoheadrightarrow] \&
            \bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} \mathrm{res}(H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2])
            \\
            \mathrm{Coker} F \arrow[r,"j"] \&{X}  .
            \end{tikzcd}
            \]

\end{document}


Add the zeros, it's that simple.
In order to keep in the margins, I also move the initial and final columns objects nearer to the next and make the diagram in \small size.
You should be consistent in your input, so I defined more operator names (\inf is already defined).
I also removed useless braces and changed \& into &, which is simpler: ampersand replacement is needed only when the diagram is passed as the argument to a command (which is the case for beamer).
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加

%\usepackage{float}% what for?

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}   

\usepackage{hyperref}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\small

%% local command for shorter input
\newcommand{\bop}[1]{%
  \mathop{\smash[b]{\bigoplus\limits_{#1}}}%
}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em]
&[-0.5em] 0 \arrow[d] & 0 \arrow[d] & 0 \arrow[d] &[-1.5em]
\\
& \Ker F\arrow[r] \arrow[d]
& \Sha(E/K)[2] \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
& \Ker H \arrow[d]
\\
& H^1(\Gal(L/K),E(L)) \arrow[r,"\inf"] \arrow[d, "F"]
& H^1(G_K,E)[2] \arrow[r,"\res"] \arrow[d,"G"]
& \res(H^1(G_K,E)[2]) \arrow[d,"H"] \arrow[r]
& 0
\\
0 \arrow[r]
& \bop{v\in M_K} H^1(\Gal(L_w/K_v),E(L_w))
    \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
& \bop{v\in M_K} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2]
    \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
& \bigoplus\limits_{v\in M_K} \res(H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2])
\\
& \Coker F \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[d]
& \Coker G \arrow[d]
\\
& 0 & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\caption{A diagram with exact rows and columns}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

I removed hooks and double heads because they're implied by exactness.

A word of advice: if you are required to use smfart, don't load geometry nor fancyhdr: the people at SMF would be annoyed.

If you want a caption, place the diagram inside a figure environment.

I want to add two ''0→'' to the position in the attached image. However, when I try to add 0\arrow[r], the arrow becomes small and doesn't display properly.

@BrauerManinobstruction You draw a diagram and ask about quite a different one. How am I supposed to know where your zeros should go?

@BrauerManinobstruction Check the edit

Thank you. The current state is almost fine, but there's just one more point: I want to remove the '0' from '$\mathrm{Ker}H \to 0$' and add '$\mathrm{res}(H^1(G_K,E)[2]) \to 0$'. However, when I try to do this, the arrow flies off in a strange direction.

@BrauerManinobstruction The changes were straightforward.

I heartily thank you.
